# How can I fix boot issue on Ubuntu Mate microSDCard (was working on raspberry pi3)

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, mount, raspberrypi

I had a raspberry pi3 running the following ubuntu version on a sdcard:

ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi

It ran for quite a few years with no issue. Recently however, I logged on and rebooted and was presented with black screen and some messages. The last line stated:

end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179-2).

I looked online for possible ways to fix this, I ultimately ran the following command:

sudo fsck -yf /dev/sda1

which returned:

fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
0X41: Dirty  bit is set. FS was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
Automatically removing dirty bit.
Performing changes.
/dev/sda1: 121 files, 2667/204341 clusters

I then must have at some point ran umount to unmount the partition.

Now when I start the raspberry pi, its just a black screen, I read that the file system is most likely still intact but I can no longer see any files on the card if I try to view it in file manager on another raspberry pi.

My question is, can anyone tell me if there is any way to restore this sdcard boot partition and file partition. Before I touched anything I saw on the card while connected with usb/microsd adapater and when viewing from the "eject" button the following:

MXT-USB Storage Device(PI_ROOT, PI_BOOT)

Before I entered the commands above I saw on the filesystem (df -h)

Filesystem              Mounted on
/dev/sda1               /media/pi/PI_BOOT
/dev/sda2               /media/pi/PI_ROOT

As you can see I am no linux expert and dealing with boot issues is definitely new territory for me as the raspberry pi running Ubuntu was stable for many years.

I'm hoping someone can help me try to fix it. I have a windows PC and a raspberry pi 2 to work with, the raspberry pi 3 is the one with the messed up sdcard.

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: It’s not unusual for SD cards to get this kind of problem if at some point they were not shutdown properly. From what you say it sounds like this has happened. I’d suggest you reinstall from scratch. It’s a good idea to keep an image of your working card so that you can quickly recover from this kind of problem. It’s possible that the card is damaged inside not usable again but you can only establish that by trying a reinstall.

Comment: Ubuntu-MATE being a *flavor* of Ubuntu, reached EOL after only 3 years, ie. 2019-April - https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/19425